# fusionar objetos dentro de un objeto javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
let tos = [
  [
    {
      "productId": "u55bbzrzazirbeerkrmv",
    }
  ],
  [
     {"productId": "9zjpe26609e4nrqpo78z"},
     {"productId": "8a4aefap014ec6t5o5kg"},
   ],
];
```

necesito fusionar los objetos hijos adentro del padre para que quede así:

```
let tos = [
  {"productId": "u55bbzrzazirbeerkrmv"},
  {"productId": "9zjpe26609e4nrqpo78z"},
  {"productId": "8a4aefap014ec6t5o5kg"}  
];
```

He intentado recorrerlo y ponerlo en diferentes objetos, pero no es eficiente, alguna idea?
gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siempre que tengas objetos anidados dentro de otros arrays y quieras sacarlos al mismo nivel usa la función [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
let tos = [
  [
    {
      "productId": "u55bbzrzazirbeerkrmv",
    }
  ],
  [
     {"productId": "9zjpe26609e4nrqpo78z"},
     {"productId": "8a4aefap014ec6t5o5kg"},
  ],
];

console.log(tos.flat());
```

La función `flat()` acepta un parámetro que indica la profundidad a la que aplanar, por defecto aplana 1 nivel de profundidad:

```js
const ejemplo = [ 1, 2, [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, [ 7, 8, [ 9 ] ] ] ];

console.log(ejemplo);
console.log(ejemplo.flat());
console.log(ejemplo.flat(2));
console.log(ejemplo.flat(3));
```